# How to set LIKE clause CI

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

controller:

```
function search()
    {
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $query = $this->membership_model->search();
        var_dump($query->result());}
```

Model:

```
function search()
    {
    $match = $this->input->post('Search');
    $this->db->like('title',$match);
    $q = $this->db->get('feeds');
    return $q;
    }
```

i want to select from my database all rows where title contains $match but it returns me all of the rows. I have a input form where i insert the word. And in model i want to search the word in every title and to return only those titles that contain the word from my input form. 
form:

```
echo anchor('site/search','Search')."<br/><br/>";
    echo form_input('search','search');
```

Comment: What is the URL you are going to?  Are you sure `Search` is being POSTed correctly?  How are you submitting your form?

Comment: check your last executed query in model.

Comment: i put only the third row in model and it returns me all the rows. that means like clause don't work                                                   echo anchor('site/search','Search')."<br/><br/>";                  echo form_input('search'); this is my form

Comment: By your last code, you don't have a form on your page, so nothing being sent by clicking on search, instead you are passing a empty value since model can reach input value or must not. In addition to @Denmark answer, add the form_open call. Also, documentation: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understand the question but i think this code is what you need

Model:

```
function search($match){
    $this->db->like('title',$match);
    $q = $this->db->get('feeds');
    return $q->result();
}
```

Controller:

```
function search_title()
    {
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $search_value = $this->input->post('search');
        $this->data['title'] = $this->membership_model->search($search_value );
     }
```

View:

```
 <table>
    <?php foreach($title as $value) : ?>
     <tr>
        <td> <?=$value->nameofcolumn; ?> </tr> //change the word nameofcolumn to the name of the column in your database what column you want to fetch
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </table>
```